# How can I send a base64 image to a discord webhook?

Tags: javascript, discord, webhooks

To the background: I take a screenshot of the body of the current page (using html2canvas) and want to send this screenshot to my discord webhook (without discord.js).
I would like to send a base64 image to a discord webhook, so that at the end an image is displayed in the discord channel. Can you tell me how to change my code to make it work?

I use the following code:

```
const whurl = "-enter discord webhook-";

const screenshotTarget = document.body;

html2canvas(screenshotTarget).then((canvas) => {
    const base64image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");

    const msg = {

        "embeds": [{
                "image": {
                    "url": base64image
                }
            }
        ]
    }

    fetch(whurl + "?wait=true", {
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": JSON.stringify(msg)
    })
    .then(a => a.json()).then()
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] your question to clarify where the problem is? What is the current result, and what did you expect?

Comment: Have changed it better this way? I just want to send a base64 image to a discord webhook so that in the end an image comes out in the discord channel.

Comment: Which part of your code does _not_ work? It is not clear from your question which part of it you're having problem(s) with.

Comment: The code doesn't work in general and I don't know how to send a base64 image to a discord webhook - that's my problem. The code works when I want to send text, but not with a base64 image. And so I ask if someone can help me to change the code so that it works or maybe has a code example?

Comment: Do you guys have any ideas? I would really appreciate it.